# Gradle: sourceSets not working as expected

Tags: android, gradle, groovy

Gradle: sourceSets not working as expected.

Here is my code:

```
android {
    ...

    defaultConfig {
        applicationId "com.firsthash.smartyoutubetv2"
        minSdkVersion 14
        targetSdkVersion 25
        versionCode 111
        versionName "6.8.39"
        multiDexEnabled = true

        testInstrumentationRunner "android.support.test.runner.AndroidJUnitRunner"
    }

    sourceSets {
        main {
            res.srcDirs = ['src/main/res', 'src/main/res-exoplayer', 'src/main/res-xwalk', 'src/main/res-webview']
        }
        debug {
            res.srcDirs = ['src/main/res', 'src/main/res-exoplayer', 'src/main/res-xwalk', 'src/main/res-webview']
        }
    }

    productFlavors {
        full {
        }
        beta {
            applicationIdSuffix ".beta"
        }
    }

}
```

The problem. Everything goes ok until I try to do an update of any project's layout file. All changes that I've made didn't reflected on the final application. I figured out that to obtain right behavior I need to manually delete project's 'build' directory. This directory contains cached build files. Such happens when I built apk using 'gradle: installDebug task' or Android Studio internal build system.

**UPD**: best workaround that could find is to use flavor dimensions: http://tools.android.com/tech-docs/new-build-system/user-guide#TOC-Multi-flavor-variants

Comment: Do you think the problem relies on Gradle not checking that layout files have changed? So the cached files from the build folder are used? You may let your tasks depend on the clean task as a workaround, but you would totally loose the caching feature.

Comment: I don't think this is Gradle problem. I read quite a lot about sourceSets. And no one mention such behavior. Don't know, maybe I just misconfigured something.